# Ariba Framework - Responsive UI Front End?

Tags: java, user-interface, responsive-design, sap-ariba

I want to quickly develop an application with default CRUD and search with responsive UI design which works in PC, Tablet and Mobile.

I searched and found the Ariba framework, and I want to know if the pages designed in the Ariba framework are (or can be) responsive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are able to build in responsiveness via CSS but it is not built into the Ariba Framework right now.